# Any morphemes that affect valency and aspect?

Tags: syntax, morphology, aspect, valency

I'll give an example of what I mean by this. In Tongan, there is a verbal suffix *-'i* that can either introduce a new argument or seemingly alter the aspect of the verb.

In (1) below, ‘the girl’ is an oblique argument. With *-’i* in (2), the valency of the clause increases by one and ‘the girl’ is now the object, marked with absolutive case. So we know that *-'i* is like an applicative suffix in that it increases clausal valency.

> (1)
> `Na’e sio 'a  Sione ki  he  ta'ahine`
> `PST  see ABS Sione OBL DEF girl`
> ‘Sione saw the girl.’
>
> (2)
> `Na’e sio-'i e   Sione a   he  ta'ahine`
> `PST  see-'i ERG Sione ABS DEF girl`
> ‘Sione stared at the girl.’
>
> <sup>(Macdonald, 2005, p. 279)</sup>

Now let's look at an instance where *-'i* has no direct effect on the valency of the clause:

> (3)
> `na’e ta  ’e  Sione 'a   Mele`
> `PST  hit ERG Sione  ABS Mele`
> ‘Sione hit (at) Mele.’
>
> (4)
> `na’e ta-'i  ’e  Sione 'a   Mele`
> `PST  hit-'i ERG Sione  ABS Mele`
> ‘Sione hit Mele (and it got her).’
>
> <sup>(Tchekhoff et al., 1981, p. 35)</sup>

In (3) and (4), there is an ergative and absolutive argument, being the agent and patient, respectively. Thus, the addition of *-'i* doesn't change the valency of the clause. In (4), but not (3), however, it is entailed that the event of Sione hitting Mele was actually completed, rather than simply initiated. In other words, *-'i* gives (4) perfective aspect.

It seems that *-'i* seems to have a dual function of either increasing valency or perfectivizing a verb (or maybe both simultaneously). I'm wondering if there are any other examples anybody can think of of languages where this happens. It doesn't necessarily need to be perfective aspect and it doesn't necessarily need to be an applicative. For example, the applicative in Indonesian can derive an iterative meaning without changing the valency of a verb.

Does anybody know of any examples in other languages where you have something like this? I'm looking specifically for verbal morphemes.

Comment: Your examples were all messed up in Markdown so I’ve edited your question to make them look as intended (unfortunately, representing interlinear glosses in Markup requires treating textual examples as computer code). You should edit further to include the names of the articles/works you’re quoting – “Macdonald 2005” is meaningless without a bibliography.

Comment: it's a reconstructed language, but PIE has some verbal formations used for deriving verbs of a different aspect than the root's inherent aktionsart that also form verbs with a specific valency (e.g. nasal imperfectives are generally transitive, whilst y-imperfectives are usually intransitive and/or deponent when formed from the Ø-grade, and transitive when formed from the accented e-grade). Depending on whether the root verb is transitive or intransitive, some of those derived verbs may be considered causatives or (medio)-passives